# How do I save indexPath.row as global integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When someone taps on a table view cell, I would like to save the indexPath.row of what they are tapping on into an integer so I can do things in another method with that number. How do I save it? When I do the following, I get warnings:

.h

```
@property NSInteger *songIndex;
```

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.songIndex = indexPath.row;
    // Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')
}
- (void)otherMethod {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [user setObject:[song objectAtIndex:self.songIndex] forKey:@"song"];
    // Warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
}
```

Comment: Show us the warnings.

Comment: You don't want a global variable. You want an instance variable or property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSInteger is not a class so you can not create object as pointer so Just remove the * from your declaration.

and you define that as property so access specifier should be (nonatomic,assign)

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *songIndex;
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

UPDATE :

Try to use NSNumber Class

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This makes songIndex always = 0 as well.

Comment: please debug and check after assigning the value in didselectrow method did the value update in songIndex?

Comment: Oops, no it works now. But it crashes and gives this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * before songIndex.
You should also be setting up your properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger songIndex;
```

NSInteger is a primitive type which returns its variable and doesn't require a pointer.

However if you CAN use a pointer to a primitive type such as BOOLs, Floats, Integers, etc.

```
NSInteger *songIndex;
[user setObject:[song objectAtIndex:&songIndex] forKey:@"song"];
```

Comment: This makes songIndex always = 0.

Comment: When and where are you calling your otherMethod? What I've shown you should be working. You should log the songIndex property once you set it in didSelectRow, if it works there, then it's getting lost somewhere else down the line.

Comment: Silly question but are you testing this with tapping on rows other than the first?

Answer (score 0):

In .h

@property int songIndex;

In .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
     self.songIndex =(int) indexPath.row; 
 } 
- (void)otherMethod { 
     PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; 
     [user setObject:[song objectAtIndex:self.songIndex] forKey:@"song"]; 
 }
```

**OR**
In .h

```
@property NSIndexPath (nonatomic,strong) songIndex;
```

In .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
     self.songIndex = indexPath; 
 } 
- (void)otherMethod { 
      PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; 
      [user setObject:[song objectAtIndex:self.songIndex.row]  forKey:@"song"]; 
 }
```